# Can't set up Vue-Grid-layout in my application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to follow the setup guide [here](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) to add the grid layout into my Electron/Vue application. I'm getting an error "Error: Layout must be an array!"

My code is below...

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="logo" src="~@/assets/logo.png" alt="electron-vue">
    <main>
      <div class="left-side">
        <span class="title">
          Connection to OMS Database
        </span>
        <system-information></system-information>
      </div>

      <div class="right-side">
        <grid-layout
            :layout="layout"
            :col-num="12"
            :row-height="30"
            :is-draggable="true"
            :is-resizable="true"
            :vertical-compact="true"
            :margin="[10, 10]"
            :use-css-transforms="true"
    >

        <grid-item v-for="item in layout"
                   :x="item.x"
                   :y="item.y"
                   :w="item.w"
                   :h="item.h"
                   :i="item.i">
            {{item.i}}
        </grid-item>
    </grid-layout>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import SystemInformation from './LandingPage/SystemInformation'

  import VueGridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout'; 

  var GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout; 
  var GridItem = VueGridLayout.GridItem; 

  var testLayout = [
        {"x":0,"y":0,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"0"},
        {"x":2,"y":0,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"1"},
        {"x":4,"y":0,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"2"},
        {"x":6,"y":0,"w":2,"h":3,"i":"3"},
        {"x":8,"y":0,"w":2,"h":3,"i":"4"},
        {"x":10,"y":0,"w":2,"h":3,"i":"5"},
        {"x":0,"y":5,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"6"},
        {"x":2,"y":5,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"7"},
        {"x":4,"y":5,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"8"},
        {"x":6,"y":4,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"9"},
        {"x":8,"y":4,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"10"},
        {"x":10,"y":4,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"11"},
        {"x":0,"y":10,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"12"},
        {"x":2,"y":10,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"13"},
        {"x":4,"y":8,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"14"},
        {"x":6,"y":8,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"15"},
        {"x":8,"y":10,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"16"},
        {"x":10,"y":4,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"17"},
        {"x":0,"y":9,"w":2,"h":3,"i":"18"},
        {"x":2,"y":6,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"19"}
    ];



  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    components: { SystemInformation, GridItem, GridLayout  },
    layout: testLayout,
    methods: {
      open (link) {
        this.$electron.shell.openExternal(link)
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I tried importing the library using import and require but I keep getting the array issue. Not sure why it's going wrong.

Thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: Your layout is a data value yet you have it on the same level as the vue objects. try changing it to `data: function () { return { layout: testLayout } }` so that it's added to the data layer and becomes available for template injection.

Comment: Hey Justin! I actually managed to fix it. Forgot the return alright thanks though for getting back to me. Would of solved it and all! I need to get a better understanding of Vue

Comment: No problem, everyone has to learn sometime somewhere